# polyglossia and Portuguese

Tags: xetex, luatex, hyphenation, polyglossia

What is the current incantation for making hyphenation work with polyglossia? In olden times, ie. two years ago, I used `\setmainlanguage{portuges}`. It doesn’t work anymore... I get no hyphenation. I’ve tried `\setmainlanguage{portuguese}`, and xetex answers me back with

`` Package polyglossia Warning: No hyphenation patterns were loaded for `portuguese' (polyglossia) I will use \language=\l@nohyphenation instead on input line 12. ``

spitting this back at me:

[image: the result: no hyphenation]

Digging around I’ve found `\setmainlanguage[variant=brazilian]{portuguese}`, which gives me this error...

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \l@portuges 
l.5 ...mainlanguage[variant=brazilian]{portuguese}
```

... but actually hyphenates (luatex doesn’t give the error, but also doesn’t hyphenate):

[image: result with hyphenation]

What am I to do? I’m using the most recent packages from Arch Linux.

Here is the minimal working example I am using:

```
\documentclass[12pt,book,twoside,imperialvopaper,final]{memoir}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{portuguese}
%% \setmainlanguage[variant=brazilian]{portuguese}

\begin{document}
Nullam eu ante vel est convallis dignissim.  Fusce suscipit, wisi nec
facilisis facilisis, est dui fermentum leo, quis tempor ligula erat
quis odio.  Nunc porta vulputate tellus.  Nunc rutrum turpis sed pede.
Sed bibendum.  Aliquam posuere.  Nunc aliquet, augue nec adipiscing
interdum, lacus tellusmalesuada massa, quis varius mi purus non odio.
Pellentesque condimentum, magna ut suscipit hendrerit, ipsum augue
ornare nulla, non luctus diamnequesitamet urna.  Curabitur
vulputate vestibulum lorem.
\end{document}
```

Comment: I didn't receive the error message, what you mentioned? But I'm using `MikTeX V2.9` in `Win10`, apart from your post, what is the purpose of using the global option `book`

Comment: Do you have the option to switch from `polyglossia` to `babel`?